# How to remove the error reported by lint check, in the style of the vue file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

[image: The code screenshot]

How to **remove** the **Red wavy** lines？

Comment: Once close project and open again. Sometimes this error solve by doing this.

Comment: I do that ,but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **useEslint: true** to false in **config/index.js**

Comment: I tried, and `npm run dev`,it didn't work. useEslint: false,  showEslintErrorsInOverlay: false,